# Unable to upload a file from sagemaker notebook to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am attempting to upload my cleaned (and split data using kfold) to s3 so that I can use sagemaker to create a model using it (since sagemaker wants an s3 file with training and test data). However, whenever I attempt to upload the csv to s3 it runs but I don't see the file in s3.

I have tried changing which folder I access in sagemaker, or trying to upload different types of files none of which work. In addition, I have tried the approaches in similar Stack Overflow posts without success.

Also note that I am able to manually upload my csv to s3, just not through sagemaker automatically.

The code below is what I currently have to upload to s3, which I have copied directly from AWS documentation for file uploading using sagemaker.

```
import io
import csv
import boto3

#key = "{}/{}/examples".format(prefix,data_partition_name)
#url = 's3n://{}/{}'.format(bucket, key)
name = boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket('nc-demo-sagemaker').name
print(name)
boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket('nc-demo-sagemaker').upload_file('train', '/')
print('Done writing to {}'.format('sagemaker bucket'))
```

I expect that when I run that code snippet, I am able to upload the training and test data to the folder I want for use in creating sagemaker models.

Comment: Does your SageMaker instance have an IAM role with s3 Read/Write permissions?

Comment: I think I have read/write permission since I can add and remove files manually, do I need a different type of permission to read/write from sagemaker?

Comment: Your IAM user has a role with permissions, which is what dictates whether you can manually upload the CSV via the s3 console. SageMaker notebooks actually have their own IAM role, which will require you to explicitly add S3 permissions. You can see this in the SageMaker console, the default IAM role is prefaced with `SageMaker-XXX`

Comment: Ah, I was using a different role in sagemaker vs s3. It works when I use the same role as s3 in sagemaker. Also have to make sure to specify the file name that needs to be used in s3.  Thanks!

Comment: Accepting the answer that helped the most below helps other users more easily find this! I see this question a bunch and having the green "answered" color makes users much more likely to stumble into this thread.

Answer (score 3):

The issue may be due to a lack of proper S3 permissions for your SageMaker notebook.

Your IAM user has a role with permissions, which is what dictates whether you can manually upload the CSV via the S3 console.

SageMaker notebooks actually have their own IAM role, which will require you to explicitly add S3 permissions. You can see this in the SageMaker console, the default IAM role is prefaced with `SageMaker-XXX`. You can either edit this SageMaker created IAM role, or attach existing IAM roles that include read/write permissions for S3.

Answer (score 3):

I always upload files from Sagemaker notebook instance to S3 using this code. This will upload all the specified folder's contents to S3. Alternatively, you can specify a single file to upload.

```
import sagemaker


s3_path_to_data = sagemaker.Session().upload_data(bucket='my_awesome_bucket', 
                                                  path='local/path/data/train', 
                                                  key_prefix='my_crazy_project_name/data/train')
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Import sagemaker library and use sagemaker session to upload and download files to/from s3 bucket.

```
import sagemaker

sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session(default_bucket='MyBucket')
upload_data = sagemaker_session.upload_data(path='local_file_path', key_prefix='my_prefix')

print('upload_data : {}'.format(upload_data))
```

Comment: I had the same issue and including the default bucket kwarg resolved it for me. Thanks!